# updating dictionary in a nested loop

Tags: python, dictionary

In the code below, I would like to update the fruit_dict dictionary with the mean price of each row. But the code is not working as expected. Kindly help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

price=np.array(range(20)).reshape(5,4)  #sample data for illustration

fruit_keys = []    # list of keys for dictionary
for i in range(5):
    key = "fruit_" + str(i)
    fruit_keys.append(key)

# initialize a dictionary     
fruit_dict = dict.fromkeys(fruit_keys)
fruit_list = []
# print(fruit_dict)

# update dictionary values 
for i in range(price.shape[1]): 
    for key,value in fruit_dict.items():
        for j in range(price.shape[0]):
            fruit_dict[key] = np.mean(price[j])
        
    fruit_list.append(fruit_dict)

fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_list)
print(fruit_df)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You have too many nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the dictionary with the string pattern you can append the values for the means of rows as a string pattern by iterating the rows only.
In case if you have a dictionary with a certain pattern you can update the value in a single loop by assigning the key as the pattern which you need for displaying. you don't need to create an additional list for creating a data frame instead you can refer the documentation for creating data frames from dictionary itself [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). I have provided a sample output which may be suitable for your requirement.
In case you need an output with mean value as a column and fruits as rows you can use the below implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

row = 5
column = 4
price = np.array(range(20)).reshape(row, column)  # sample data for illustration

# initialize a dictionary
fruit_dict = {}
for j in range(row):
    fruit_dict['fruit_'+str(j)] = np.mean(price[j])

fruit_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fruit_dict,orient='index',columns=['mean_value'])
print(fruit_df)
```

This will provide an output like below. As I already mentioned you can create the data frame as you wish from a dictionary by referring the above data frame documentation.

```
           mean_value
fruit_0         1.5
fruit_1         5.5
fruit_2         9.5
fruit_3        13.5
fruit_4        17.5
`
```

Comment: Sangeerththan-b,

Your answer helped me to take a fresh approach to the solution. Thank you

Comment: @Joaquim Glad I could help solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't nest the loop over the range and the dictionary items, you should iterate over them together. You can do this with `enumerate()`.

You're also not using `value`, so there's no need to use `items()`.

```
for i, key in enumerate(fruit_dict):
    fruit_dict[key] = np.mean(price[j])
```

Comment: Yes, very correct

Answer (score 0):

Could arrive on a solution based on the answer provided by Sangeerththan. Please find the same below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

fruit_dict = {}
fruit_list =[]

price=np.array(range(40)).reshape(4,10)

for i in range(price.shape[0]):
    mark_price = np.square(price[i])
        
    for j in range(mark_price.shape[0]):
        fruit_dict['proj_fruit_price_'+str(j)] = np.mean(mark_price[j])
        
    fruit_list.append(fruit_dict.copy())
    
fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this instead of your loops:

```py
fruit_keys = []    # list of keys for dictionary
for i in range(5):
    key = "fruit_" + str(i)
    fruit_keys.append(key)

out = {fruit_keys[index]: np.mean(price[index]) for index in range(price.shape[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'fruit_1': '1.5', 'fruit_2': '5.5', 'fruit_3': '9.5', 'fruit_4': '13.5', 'fruit_5': '17.5'}
```